# Numpy - ValueError: cannot set an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, csv, numpy

So, I wrote small test code for calculating the averages from all the csv files in a folder.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='avg data from csv to csv')
parser.add_argument('--input', required = True)
parser.add_argument('--output', required = True)
args = parser.parse_args()

# Get command arguments
input_files_path = args.input
output = args.output

avg = []
for infile in glob.glob(input_files_path+"*.csv"):
        a = np.loadtxt(infile, delimiter=",")
        mean = np.mean(a, axis=0)
        avg.append((mean))
        print infile
np.savetxt(output,(avg), fmt = "%.1f", delimiter=", ")
```

but the issue now, when I am trying to save the name of the file as well in the csv file like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='avg data from csv to csv')
parser.add_argument('--input', required = True)
parser.add_argument('--output', required = True)
args = parser.parse_args()

# Get command arguments
input_files_path = args.input
output = args.output

avg = []
for infile in glob.glob(input_files_path+"*.csv"):
        a = np.loadtxt(infile, delimiter=",")
        mean = np.mean(a, axis=0)
        avg.append((infile,(mean)))
        print infile
np.savetxt(output,(avg), fmt = "%.1f", delimiter=", ")
```

it throws an error:

```
    np.savetxt(output,(avg), fmt = "%.1f", delimiter=", ")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 963, in savetxt
    X = np.asarray(X)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 235, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: cannot set an array element with a sequence
```

I don't seem to understand what the issue is. Maybe it is because I am trying to append a string to a float? I check the `fmt`s in numpy.. but I did not find anything interesting.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py:773: UserWarning: loadtxt: Empty input file: "../robalo-31.1/op.csv"
  warnings.warn('loadtxt: Empty input file: "%s"' % fname)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:2374: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return mean(axis, dtype, out)
```

Comment: I don't see the line `avg.append((infile,(mean)))` anywhere in your code.  Could you please clarify how that fits into this?

Comment: Posted. Is there something else that I am missing?
Added after the edit @mgilson

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I'm guessing that it has something to do with the `format` portion in `savetxt` -- Basically you're telling numpy to save everything as a float, but you've got strings in your data.  I can imagine that could mess up the `dtype` argument when numpy tries to convert the list to an ndarray.  Rather than using `np.savetxt`, could I recommend that you look into the excellent `csv` module for saving the output file?

Comment: Well, do you see any other way of knowing which row of the csv file contains which data?
`CSV` is surely an option. do you suggest any function in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing there's a problem with the format characters you're providing with `np.savetxt`.  (you have a string-float tuple and you're delimiter implies you're only using floats).  I would suggest `csv` for this instead:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import StringIO
>>> g = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> writer = csv.writer(g,delimiter=',')  #this is the part that is applicable
>>> writer.writerows(lst)
>>> g.seek(0)
>>> print g.read()
foo,2
bar,4
```

So I'm guessing your code could be simply:

```
with open(output,'wb') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout,delimiter=',') 
    writer.writerows(avg)
```

instead of

```
np.savetxt(output,(avg), fmt = "%.1f", delimiter=", ")
```

Comment: That would still not do the job. there is some other problem. 
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'writer'`

Comment: @user2015933 -- [It's definitely in there](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) ...

Comment: `writer = csv.writer(fout,delimiter=', ')`
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'writer'`
fyi, I imported csv.

Comment: what do you get if you just do a simple `from csv import writer` outside of your script?

Comment: Sorry. I did not read the question correctly. 
There is no error from the cmdline.

Comment: However, It is not seen from the script.

Comment: @user2015933 -- Can you print `csv.__name__` right you try to use the writer?

Comment: There are a couple reasons why this might be happening.  The first reason is that you accidentally set `csv = some_other_module` in your script -- Although that's unlikely.  The second reason it could happen is because you could have a `csv.py` file somewhere else on your pythonpath (likely the same directory as your script).  print `csv.__file__` to see where it was imported from.

Comment: You got it!. How stupid am I. I named the file csv.py. I now need to convert it back from scientific number to floating point. :)